# AFRAME I cant display informations on pictures on click

Tags: javascript, onclick, aframe, display

I am starting aframe and I cant display some informations (a small text) on pictures.

If you could help me it would be very nice.

I put the script of my pictures in the head of my html page.

```
<script id="panInfor" type="text/html">
    <a-entity class="panInfor"
      geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1"
      material="shader: flat; src: ${thumb}"
      sound="on: click; src: #click-sound"
      event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.2 1.2 1"
      event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1"
      event-set__click="_target: #text-informations;_delay: 300; material.src: ${src}"
      proxy-event="event: click; to: #text-informations; as: switch">
    </a-entity>
  </script>
```

In the asset I put this code concerning the text of my picture

```
<a-text position="1 2 -4" rotation="0 -90 0" id="text-messi" value="Greatest Of All Times" align="center">
</a-text>
```

And out of the asset, in the ascene, i put this code :

```
<a-text id="text-informations" src="#text-messi" visible="false"
      animation__click="property: visible; dur: 0; to: true; startEvents: switch" color="yellow">

    </a-text>
```

The aim of my code is just to display informations when I click on the pictures.

I wanted to display informations on pictures, retrieving the code of the tutorial of aframe "360 image gallery" but it doesnt work...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can't place one `a-text` node in the assets and refer to it from another `a-text` node - the assets are rather used to load resources like images, models, videos, sound etc.

If you add the text via the `value` attribute to the animated `a-text` entity, it's working:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-proxy-event-component/dist/aframe-proxy-event-component.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@5.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>

<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: a-entity">
  <a-entity position="0 1.6 -2" 
            geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1" 
            material="shader: flat; color: green"  
            event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.2 1.2 1" 
            event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1" 
            proxy-event="event: click; to: #text-informations; as: switch">

    <a-text id="text-informations" value="Greatest Of All Times" align="center" visible="false" 
            animation__click="property: visible; dur: 0; to: true; startEvents: switch" color="yellow">
    </a-text>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

---

I'd strongly recommend trying to [create a custom component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar), which would handle the hide-show logic:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-event-set-component@5.0.0/dist/aframe-event-set-component.min.js"></script>
<script>
// the component has to be defined before the <a-scene>
AFRAME.registerComponent("show-text", {
  // a schema, so we can provide different <a-text>s
  schema: {
    txt: {type: "selector"}
  },
  // called upon initialisation
  init: function() {
    // on each click - toggle the visibility
    this.el.addEventListener("click", evt => {
      // if the text is invalid - lets get outta here
      if (!this.data.txt) return; 
      // get the current visibility
      const visible = this.data.txt.getAttribute("visible") 
      // set the visibility to its opposite
      this.data.txt.setAttribute("visible", !visible) 
    })
  }
})
</script>
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" raycaster="objects: a-entity">
  <a-entity position="-1 1.6 -2" 
            geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1" 
            material="shader: flat; color: green"  
            event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.2 1.2 1" 
            event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1" 
            show-text="txt: #text-informations">

    <a-text id="text-informations" value="Greatest Of All Times" align="center" visible="false" 
            animation__click="property: visible; dur: 0; to: true; startEvents: switch" color="yellow">
    </a-text>
  </a-entity>
  
    <a-entity position="1 1.6 -2" 
            geometry="primitive: plane; height: 1; width: 1" 
            material="shader: flat; color: green"  
            event-set__mouseenter="scale: 1.2 1.2 1" 
            event-set__mouseleave="scale: 1 1 1" 
            show-text="txt: #text-informations2">

    <a-text id="text-informations2" value="Something Else" align="center" visible="false" 
            animation__click="property: visible; dur: 0; to: true; startEvents: switch" color="yellow">
    </a-text>
  </a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Thanks. but if I have many images, how can I do if I want to make the text appear (and disappear in a second time) according to the image I click on ?

Comment: @anton37 check the update